# SQL Server Reporting Services 2012 add-in in local mode with SharePoint 2013 working?

Tags: sharepoint, ssrs-2012

Anyone using SQL Server Reporting Services 2012 add-in in local mode with SharePoint 2013 successfully?

Reporting from a list works. But sub-reports and shared datasets (we did create and deploy an appropriate .rsds file) both lead to "file not found" errors when deployed.

Now we found that even specifying parameter values from a query doesn't work: "One or more parameters required to run the report have not been specified". The report works as soon as we specify the same values in the report itself.

Everything works within Visual Studio (2012) but fails when deployed to SharePoint. I guess those "advanced" features need some of the infrastructure you get when running in integrated mode. Can someone confirm that?

We are stuck with SQL Server 2008 R2 for now. So no integrated mode possible yet.

Update: the above was all using connection type "Microsoft SharePoint List". Just found that you cannot use connection type "XML" without integrated mode either (Error "An attempt has been made to use an unregistered data extension, 'XML'. To use this data extension, it must be registered in the Web.config file of this Web application").